# Bundle Mono Runtime with GTK# App in App Bundle for Apple Store

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono, xamarin.mac

I have an app using GTK# UI which i created using xamarin studio.I understand that Xamarin.Mac can create automatic bundles.But my project uses GTK# and does not support automatic bundle creation.I have seen this Webpage https://mhut.ch/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app

It only describe the way to create an app bundle but does not speak about bundling the mono runtime.Is there a way by which i can achieve this?